# TypeScript typings for something that adds to an existing class?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, typescript

I am trying to make a typings for Backbone-Nested-Models which adds functionality to an existing Backbone.Model:

```
/// <reference path="../backbone/backbone.d.ts" />
declare module Backbone {
    class Events {
    }

    class ModelBase extends Events {
    }

    class Model extends ModelBase {
        setRelation(attr, val, options):any;
        set(key, val, options):any;
        toJSON(options):any;
        clone(options):any;
        resetRelations(options):any;
        reset(model,options):any;
    }
}

declare module "backbone-nested-models" {
}
```

But it tells me those classes already exist.

Am I forced to add these functions to my Backbone typings themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I forced to add these functions to my Backbone typings themselves?

At the moment yes.

Please see this issue : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/819#issuecomment-108656463